# How can I deploy a django app without windows admin rights?

Tags: python, django, windows, xampp

Im trying to start developing a simple crud application using a pc with windows as the server. Since I don't have admin rights, it's getting really hard to find a solution. Ive tried using xampp lite with an usb and I got the server running, the thing is xampp lite doesnt support python interpretation.

Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it!!

Comment: You can use nginx and uwsgi for deploy on windows. http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration

Answer (score 0):

you need no manually configure your apache server to be able to serve python files. this can be done with mod_python (mod_fcgi is possilbe too and maybe others)

see http://blog.chomperstomp.com/installing-python-mod_python-on-xampp/ for a **detailed explanation for mod_python**.